# WPF - Datagrid translations in header replaced by key: when opening new window

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, internationalization, prism

I cannot show all the code, details, ... regarding this case, so I will make it as clear a possible. Sorry for that.

We have a translated dataGrid in WPF. Where translations are loaded in Header with a code behind method as follows:

```
 string[] headerDictionary =
                {
                    Properties.Resources.XXX,
                    (...) all your ressources here

                };

            for (int i = 0; i < this.ResultDataGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                DataGridColumn dgc = this.ResultDataGrid.Columns[i];
                dgc.Header = headerDictionary[i];
                dgc.Width = DataGridLength.SizeToCells;
            }
```

This is because we change langages and without this, the language in the header will not be adapted.

To solve my problem, I tried to remove this, does not help.

Moreover, in xaml we have smoething like this for translations:

```
 Header="{lex:LocTextExtension keyHere}"
```

So, on a search page, we show the results in a part (Result list), handled with Prism.

On this part, we have an alt+double click option to open the record in a news window.

When open the new window, and only in this case, we loose the translations in the dataGrid headers. They are replaced by key:xxxxxx.

If I remove the code behind for translations, then the Grid translation is not adapted for a language change.

I tried: 
- remove all special code
- Change culture twice to force reload language
- Change method for translation.

Nothing works.

The only think I can demonstrate is, that it is linked with opening a new window.

Are you aware of such problems? Have someone an idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance for support.

Answer (score 0):

After investigations, I find the following solution.

This is working, with translation and opening the new window with a double click.

All translations are correctly handled and behave as expected:

- Remove all `Header="{lex:LocTextExtension keyHere}"` in XAML
- Set all headers in code behind as follows:

  string[] headerDictionary =
                  {
                      Properties.Resources.yourKeyHere,
                      Properties.Resources.yourKeyHere,
                      Properties.Resources.yourKeyHere,
                      Properties.Resources.yourKeyHere,
                      (...)
                  };

  ```
          for (int i = 0; i < this.ResultDataGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
          {
              DataGridColumn dgc = this.ResultDataGrid.Columns[i];
              dgc.Header = headerDictionary[i];
              dgc.Width = DataGridLength.SizeToCells;
          }
  ```

Why it is like that, I cannot answer, it just works. If anyone has better or complementary answers, I will be happy to understand.